# For loop performance on multiple variables - C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance

We all know that we can declare multiple variables in a for loop like the one below

```
for ( int var1 = 0, var2 = 0, var3 = 0, var4 = 0, var5 = 0, var6 = 0; var1 < 10;
      var1++, var2++, var3++, var4++, var5++, var6++ )
{
      int result = var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6;
      Console.WriteLine( result );
}
Console.Read();
```

My Question is,

1. Can you let me know the total number of variables you can initialize in a for-loop?
2. **Do multiple variables affect the performance of for-loop?**
3. How many variable do you suggest we can use in a for-loop?

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO use one variable(which affects condition) and other initialize outside loop - much more readable.

Comment: The most loop variables I've ever used is 2, and that was pretty darn exceptional.

Comment: @harold I thank you for your reply. I definitely agree with you!

Comment: @Reniuz I apologize but can you clarify me on this 
"other initialize outside loop" ?
Thanks.

Comment: Well I mean: `int var2 = 0; var3 = 0;...varn = 0; for(int var1 = 0; var1 < 10; var1++){}` here  var2, var3, varn is "other" variables and they are outside loop and var1 is used for condition :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 3. How many variable do you suggest we can use in a for-loop?

1

This is not about perfomance. Your only concern is readability, and that suffers a lot when you use a second variable. Never needed, never useful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Code clarity is a main cause of concern in lot of professional development environment and this learning will come a long way for a lot of programmers. Though this is a very basic question, in my perspective this will help a lot of developers.

Answer (score 0):

1. As much as you can
2. Yes. In your code, the increasing statements: `var1++, var2++, var3++, var4++, var5++, var6++` does effect.
3. It's up to your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. No limit as far as I know.
2. The variable inits are executed once at the beginning, and the increments are executed at each iteration, so you can expect the inits to have negligible impact, while the increments will have a linear impact on the performance with the number of iterations.
3. Depends on what you want to do. 99% of for loops uso only one variable.

Comment: #3 make that 99.99% and you'll be within 0.01% of the truth

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When we encounter GUI controls like grids where we deal with collections, we always use two variables i.e one for the List index and the other is a display index which the user will see.